# Listener for ANY object value change?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

Is there a way to create a listener (JavaFX) for *any* changes made to *any* of an object's field?

I have a coordinate object:

```
public class Coord {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Coord(int aX, int aY) {
        x = aX;
        y = aY;
    }
}
```

I have a component that creates a coordinate object when the mouse enters and destroys it when it exits. I've attached an invalidation listener:

```
        this.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            _hoverCoord = new SimpleObjectProperty<Coord>(getCoord(event.getX(), event.getY()));
            _hoverCoord.addListener(redraw);
        });

        this.setOnMouseExited(event -> {
            _hoverCoord = null;
        });
```

When the mouse moves, I've been creating a new coordinate. Great, the invalidation fires because I'm replacing the coordinate. But this creates a whole bunch of these short-lived objects. I've resolved this by just calling the code I want directly in the mouse move, but it raised the following questions:

My first question is: Is that kind of rapid-fire object creation/destruction worth worrying about, generally? (I know that's a hard question to answer but I'm thinking in terms of garbage collection when creating tens of thousands of objects in a short time.)

My second question is: Is there a "listener" that just watches a POJO like Coord for field level changes?

My third question is: If not, is there a way to preserve Coord as a simple object and yet listen for specific field changes (without adding methods or changing the `x` and `y` from `int`)? I mean, no accessors for the fields.

My fourth question is: If not, how would I put in the accessors in Coord?

Comment: never seen _rapid fire_ - [mcve] please with a clear description what you want to achieve (and stick to one problem per question, multiples are hard to answer in a single answer :) Quick shots on 2/3: no, 4: ? what do you mean? just implement them?

Comment: Well, it fires every time the mouse moves, which is totally legitimate. It's my code that's creating and destroying the objects that is the issue. As for #4, I see numerous ways to implement the change (change Coord, wrap Coord)...@bichoFlyer's answer looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

First, transform your Coord in a JavaFX Bean:

```
public class Coord{
   private final IntegerProperty x = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "x");
   private final IntegerProperty y = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "y");

   public final void setX(int x){ this.x.set(x); }
   public final int getX(){ return x.get(); }
   public final IntegerProperty xProperty(){ return this.x; }
   
   //Repeat for y.
}
```

Then, you may add an invalidation or change listener to the x property:

```
myCoordinate.xProperty().addListener(redraw);
myCoordinate.yProperty().addListener(redraw);
```

Now, there's a question: why do you need to listen the coordinates? If you need to compute something, you may use the helper Bindings, for instance, if you want to compute x*y each time the cursor moves, then you may use:

```
productProperty.bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(
   ()->coordinate.getX() * coordinate.getY(), //Compute x*y
   coordinate.xProperty(), //dependency on x property
   coordinate.yProperty()//dependency on y property
));
```

Or you may create your readonly property:

```
private final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper product = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper(this, "product");

public Coord(){
   init();
}

private void init(){
   product.bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(
      ()->coordinate.getX() * coordinate.getY(), //Compute x*y
      coordinate.xProperty(), //dependency on x property
      coordinate.yProperty()//dependency on y property
   ));
}

public final int getProduct(){
   return product.get();
}

public final ReadOnlyIntegerProperty productProperty(){
    return product.getReadOnlyProperty();
}
```

Comment: OK: The mouse enters, the Coord is created which is derived from the MOUSE x, y by the component. I think I'd have to bind the Coord to the Mouse x, y through a helper function of the component. So I'm having trouble thinking that through.

Comment: @user3810626 have you tried with a Robot? https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/robot/Robot.html

Comment: That seems like it's for testing. That is, it simulates user interactions whereas I *have* user interactions and I'm just trying to, essentially, bind one object's properties to the mouse position.

Comment: you may also capture information, take a look to Robot.getMousePosition()

Comment: Very cool. I'm wondering if it's insane to create a Mouse object that is updated by an Event Filter at the scene level, and to have the inner component updated by that.